# Single Library Storage for multiple Site collections

Tags: document-library, bcs, site-collection

We are building portal based on SP 2010 platform which will mainly be a e-learnig site with SharePointLearning Kit. There will be ca. 100 school site collections. We will also have about 23 gigabytes of educational packages in SCORM format.

We are looking for way where we could keep our SCORM packages in single library and allow users (teachers) to take packages straight from that library and create new assignments in their classes. Since SLK integrates with sharepoint lists (where you can select list item and assign it to learners in 3 clicks), we are looking for way to display content from our SCORM library in as list view.

If you ever had this kind of problem, how did you solve it?

I was thinking about employing BCS with custom database, but since binary data storage will take place, I don't know if BCS can handle binary data.

What are Your recommendations for storing such amount of files?

**EDIT**

After doing some research I managed to make BCS display my materials meta data, but external lists are not document libraries, and SLK doesn't integrate with them. So we came up with idea where there will be one library on one site collection and visual web part which will allow to browse it and copy selected packages into school site document library.

Comment: Is the 23 GB of files made up of a few big files or many small files?

Comment: Not quite sure how big they will be, but I think defintely less than 100MB each and probably less than 50 megs most of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RBS, with a separate database/site collection to store the data, so not all of your sites are using it. This will still take up considerable amount of data on your server. Check out my blog post for additional considerations. http://davidlozzi.com/2011/08/12/storing-your-sharepoint-files-outside-of-the-database-rbs/

If the training material will be purely static, you may want to consider storing it else where, maybe on a media server, and use a link library to manage it in SharePoint. Much more light weight on SharePoint. And your night backups will be a lot smaller.

Answer (score 0):

For the large binary data you can use [Remote BLOB Storage (RBS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748638.aspx).